# builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following function to calculate the simple moving average for my data frame.

```
## data from 
import yfinance as yf
symbols=[ 'SPY', 'TSLA', 'AAPL', 'CAKE', 'JBLU', 'MSFT']
data = yf.download(symbols, start="2015-01-01", end="2021-04-20")
def trend(df, fast, slow):
  Dataset= pd.DataFrame(index=df.index)
  Dataset['SlowSMA'] = df['Close'].rolling(slow).mean()
  Dataset['FastSMA'] = df['Close'].rolling(fast).mean()
  return Dataset
```

This works fine if I have one stock as there is only one close, however, it gives me the following issue

builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

I want to iterate in the data  for each ticker in the data frame and save it in the Dataset by its name so I know which one is which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified a bit your code but this works :

```
import yfinance as yf
symbols=[ 'SPY', 'TSLA', 'AAPL', 'CAKE', 'JBLU', 'MSFT']
data = yf.download(symbols, start="2015-01-01", end="2021-04-20")
```

```
def stock_trend(df, fast, slow):
    Dataset= pd.DataFrame(index=df.index)
    Dataset['SlowSMA']= df.rolling(slow).mean().values
    Dataset['FastSMA']= df.rolling(fast).mean().values
    return Dataset
```

```
def all_stock_trends(df, fast, slow, stocks: list, value_type: str):
    allst = []
    for stock in stocks:
        data = df[value_type][stock]
        st = stock_trend(data, fast, slow)
        allst.append(st)
    
    all_st = pd.concat(allst, axis=1)
    all_st.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([stocks, ['SlowSMA', 'FastSMA']])
    return all_st
```

Then you can do :

```
all_stocks_close = all_stock_trends(data, '1d', '1d', symbols, 'Close')
```

Which gives the following as output :

```
SPY TSLA    AAPL    CAKE    JBLU    MSFT
SlowSMA FastSMA SlowSMA FastSMA SlowSMA FastSMA SlowSMA FastSMA SlowSMA FastSMA SlowSMA FastSMA
Date                                                
2014-12-31  205.539993  205.539993  44.481998   44.481998   27.594999   27.594999   50.310001   50.310001   15.860000   15.860000   46.450001   46.450001
2015-01-02  205.429993  205.429993  43.862000   43.862000   27.332500   27.332500   50.110001   50.110001   15.790000   15.790000   46.759998   46.759998
2015-01-05  201.720001  201.720001  42.018002   42.018002   26.562500   26.562500   50.200001   50.200001   15.220000   15.220000   46.330002   46.330002
2015-01-06  199.820007  199.820007  42.256001   42.256001   26.565001   26.565001   49.820000   49.820000   14.970000   14.970000   45.650002   45.650002
2015-01-07  202.309998  202.309998  42.189999   42.189999   26.937500   26.937500   51.700001   51.700001   15.100000   15.100000   46.230000   46.230000
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2021-04-13  412.859985  412.859985  762.320007  762.320007  134.429993  134.429993  57.610001   57.610001   20.770000   20.770000   258.489990  258.489990
2021-04-14  411.450012  411.450012  732.229980  732.229980  132.029999  132.029999  58.200001   58.200001   20.830000   20.830000   255.589996  255.589996
2021-04-15  415.869995  415.869995  738.849976  738.849976  134.500000  134.500000  57.689999   57.689999   20.690001   20.690001   259.500000  259.500000
2021-04-16  417.260010  417.260010  739.780029  739.780029  134.160004  134.160004  57.840000   57.840000   20.299999   20.299999   260.739990  260.739990
2021-04-19  415.209991  415.209991  714.630005  714.630005  134.839996  134.839996  58.200001   58.200001   20.190001   20.190001   258.739990  258.739990
1585 rows × 12 columns
```

To access the data for one stock you can then simply do :

```
SPY_stock = all_stocks_close['SPY']
```